# JQuery - Trouble with click / link handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm having some trouble getting this work, I'm using JQuery to get a list of results from mySQL, the results include a name and handler link (JQuery) that should trigger a *function/event*, but it is not working for some reason

Here is the code from my first page:

This script runs a query and gets the results from the **ajax_load.php** file using JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#lets_library").bind('submit',function() {
                var value_name = $('#name').val();

                if(value_name)
                    {
                    $("#find_library").html('Loading results...');
                    }


                $.post('ajax_load.php',{value_name:value_name}, function(data){

                    $("#search_results_library").html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This other script in the same first page is for the click handler, showing the **ID** clicked, but it is not working:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    /// shows my ID from the result row ///
    $('.next-click').click(function() {
    alert("my id: " + $(this).data("id"));

    });
});
</script>
```

This is part of the code from the **ajax_load.php** that returns the results with the ***link*** and ***ID*** to be clicked:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_query))
{


echo '
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<td> 
'; 
echo '<a href="#" class="next-click" data-id="'; echo $row['ID']; echo '">';
echo $row['name'];
echo '</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</table>';

}
```

The problem is, when I click on the link it adds an # to the end of the URL page and nothing happens like the script is not even there. 
Please help!

Comment: You can correct this: 1) jQuery `.bind` is deprecated, use `.on` like @Arun P Jhony showed, 2) THE OPERATOR in your PHP while loop is an ASSIGNMENT operator, not a comparison operator. Change it to `==` or `===`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the link is created dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /// shows my ID from the result row ///
    $('#search_results_library').on('click', '.next-click', function () {
        alert("my id: " + $(this).data("id"));
    });
});
```

When you use `$('.next-click').click(..)`, the click handler will get registered to only those `next-click` elements which exists in the page when the script is executed. The elements added later will not get the triggers.

So the solution is to bind the handler to an element which already exists in the dom(which is an ancestor of the target element), but pass a additional selector which will specify the actual target we are looking for. jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method provides this functionality

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#search_results_library").on('click', '.next-click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("my id: " + $(this).data("id"));

});
```